# How do I use token(post) Mysql with node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am a newbie programmer. I've been making a very small website. I met little error. I've found some solutions. But I haven't had an answer yet.

If you don't mind, Please give me your touhgt. T^T

I connected node.js with Mysql. 'GET' is running without any problem. but 'POST' section can't get some data which I type on the webpage.

The thing I wonder is that why 'POST' don't get data.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');

var client = mysql.createConnection({
  user: 'root',
  password: 'PASSWORD',
  database: 'Company'
});

var app = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(8080, function(){
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080');
});

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  fs.readFile('list.html', 'utf8', function(error, data) {
    client.query('SELECT * FROM products', function (error, results) {
       response.send(ejs.render(data, {
        data: results
      }));
    });
  });
});


app.get('/delete/:id', function(request, response) { 
  client.query('DELETE FROM products WHERE id=?', [request.param('id')], function() {
    response.redirect('/');
  });
});

app.get('/insert', function(request, response) { 
  fs.readFile('insert.html', 'utf8', function (error, data) {
  response.send(data);
  });
}); 

app.post('/insert', function(request, response) {
  var body = request.body;

  client.query('INSERT INTO products (name, modelnumber, series) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'[
    body.name, body.modelnumber, body.series
    ], function() {
      response.redirect('/');
  });
});

app.get('/edit/:id', function(request, response) { 
  fs.readFile('edit.html', 'utf8', function(error, data) {
    client.query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?', [
      request.param('id')
    ], function(error, result) {
      response.send(ejs.render(data, {
        data: result[0]
      }));
    });
  });
});

app.post('/edit/:id', function(request, response) { 
  var body = request.body;

  client.query('UPDATE products SET name=?, modelnumber=?, series=? WHERE id=?', [
    body.name, body.modelnumber, body.series, request.param('id')
    ], function() {
      response.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

The error message

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>       at app.get.fs.readFile.client.query.response.send.ejs.render.data (/home/han/app.js:46:9)
>       at callbacks (/home/han/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
>       at param (/home/han/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
>       at pass (/home/han/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
>       at Router._dispatch (/home/han/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:173:5)
>       at Object.router (/home/han/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
>       at next (/home/han/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
>       at Object.expressInit [as handle] (/home/han/node_modules/express/lib/middleware.js:30:5)
>       at next (/home/han/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
>       at Object.query [as handle] (/home/han/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/query.js:45:5)

When I tried to change array values to 'value' app.post('/insert') section, the webpage showed 'value'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that request.body is undefined. It is undefined, because you have not configured Express to parse the body. To do this, you need to install the module body-parser

```
npm install body-parser
```

Next, require body-parse in your code

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

And set it as middleware after you initialized Express.

```
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Your request.body should now equal to the form.

EDIT1:

Try this for your insert query

```
app.post('/insert', function(request, response) {
  var body = request.body;

  var product = {
    name: body.name,
    modelnumber: body.modelnumber,
    series: body.series
  }
  client.query('INSERT INTO products SET ?', product, function() {
      response.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thnak you.. I tried to use your suggestion. but other error come..

**TheypError: cannot call method 'replace' of undefined at Object.SqlString.format.**

Is the problem my query?

Comment: It looks like the data you're trying to pass in your POST isn't coming through, so you're calling request.body.name for instance, which could be undefined, so it throws an error inside your parameterized query. Inside your function, call console.log(request.body) to see if your data is being correctly passed in.

Comment: I checked error. I put console.log(request.body) under var body = request.body; I can check that It gets datas on console window. but next line, there is error message.

Comment: Can you post the output of that console.log?

Comment: When I put console.log(request.body); after var body = request.body; 

I can see this error message on a console window. -->
 **{ name: 'Jae-Han', modelnumber: '0104804', series: 'RintSeries' }
TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined**

I typed name, modelnumber and series on the webpage.

Comment: Hmm, that looks right. I've updated my answer with an alternative mysql query, try that!

Comment: **OMG !!!!!!!** T^T Thank you for your solution...!!!!!! T^T really reaaly think you!! I've tried to find all over the web pages; facebook, google searchs and stackoverflow... finally, I get it!!

Comment: You're welcome :) Is there anything else, or could you mark the question as answered?

Comment: It is perfactly running. I don't need anything  for your help . :)

Comment: Could you please accept my answer then? if you don't know how, checkout http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 Thanks.

Comment: Yep. I have checked it.

Answer (score 0):

In this section:

```
app.post('/insert', function(request, response) {
  var body = request.body;

  client.query('INSERT INTO products (name, modelnumber, series) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'[
    body.name, body.modelnumber, body.series
    ], function() {
      response.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

Try to replace usage of `request.body` with `request.params`.
when using forms + post, node will interpret the fields as params on the request object.

Comment: Do I change var body = request.body to var body = request.params??

Comment: @Jae-HanPark, yes, go ahead and try that.